# active record subset by difference between updated_at and creatd_at

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

In my database for model Message, I have a created_at attribute for storing when the object was first created and a status_updated_at attribute for storing when the object has its status updated. Both of these attributes are `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`

I'm trying to find all objects in the database where status_updated_at is within 3 minutes of created_at.

I've tried `Message.where("status_updated_at<=(created_at+180.seconds)")` and `Message.where("(status_udpated_at-created_at)<=180.seconds")`.

Both of them gave me `#<Message::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3843d7c>`
. But when I try to count them, for example, `Message.where("status_updated_at<=(created_at+180.seconds)").count`, I got the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "seconds"
LINE 1: ...essages" WHERE ((status_udpated_at-created_at)<=180.seconds)
                                                               ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "messages" WHERE ((status_udpated_at-created_at)<=180.seconds)
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:620:in `async_exec'
```

How should I get the count of messages that have status_updated_at within 3 minutes (180 seconds) of created_at?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between two [`timestamp`s in PostgreSQL is an `interval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE) value and `interval`s have some convenient [text representations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT) so you can say things like:

```
Message.where('status_updated_at - created_at <= ?', '3 minutes').count
Message.where('status_updated_at - created_at <= ?', '180 seconds').count
```